# How to shuffle and print a list of emoji using python?

Tags: python, list, random, emoji

I want to generate emojis in a random way. I tried two different methods but still not habing an output mixed

```
import random

soleillever ="\U0001f305"
Soleildodo = "\U0001f634"
nuage = '\u2601'
soleilnuage = "\U0001f326"
nuageeclair = "\U0001f329"
rainbow = '\U0001f308'
termo = '\U0001F321'
soleil = '\U0001f31e'
soleil2 = "\U0001f31d"
nuageeclairpluie = "\u26C8"
flocon = "\u2744"
print(soleil,soleil2,termo,rainbow,nuageeclair,soleilnuage,nuage,flocon)


a =[rainbow + nuageeclair + soleilnuage + nuage + soleil2 + nuageeclairpluie + flocon + rainbow]
b = random.sample(a, k=len(a))
print(b)


a1 = [rainbow + nuageeclair + soleilnuage + nuage + soleil2 + nuageeclairpluie + flocon + rainbow]
b1 = random.shuffle(a1)
print(b1)
```

Here is the output with the type

```
['☁⛈❄']
 Here is b <class 'list'>

B1 gives me None
Here is b1<class 'NoneType'>
```

If someone have an advice, I will appreciate !
B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be two mistakes in your code. The first is that `random.shuffle` applies the shuffling in-place.

As per my comments, `random.shuffle` does not return anything. As such, when you assigned `b1` to the value returned by `random.shuffle`, it is set to nothing, i.e. `None` You can imagine the function as looking like this:

```
def shuffle(input):
   # do something to input
```

instead of

```
def shuffle(input):
   # do something to input
   return input
```

In your case, it should work if you do the following.

```
# normal, un-shuffled list
print(a1)
random.shuffle(a1)
print(a1) # same array, but now it has been shuffled
```

The second problem is that you create `a1`, as list of strings by using the + operation. As a result, this essentially creates a single string, contained within a list instead of a list of strings. The difference is as a follows:

```
lst0 = ['hello'] 
random.shuffle(lst0) # returns ['hello']

lst1 = ['h'+'e'+'l'+'l'+'o'] # this is identical to lst0
random.shuffle(lst1) # returns ['hello']

lst2 = ['h','e','l','l','o']
random.shuffle(lst2) # returns ['o', 'h', 'l', 'e', 'l']
```

In your case, try to use commas instead of +. That is:

```
a1 = [rainbow , nuageeclair , soleilnuage , nuage , soleil2 , nuageeclairpluie , flocon , rainbow]
```

or directly

```
a1 = ["\U0001f305","\U0001f634",'\u2601',"\U0001f326","\U0001f329",'\U0001f308','\U0001F321','\U0001f31e',"\U0001f31d","\u26C8","\u2744"]
```

Comment: `a1 = [rainbow + nuageeclair + soleilnuage + nuage + soleil2 + nuageeclairpluie + flocon + rainbow]

print('Before Shuffle',a1)
random.shuffle(a1)
print('After Shuffle',a1) `

Gives me the following output = 

`Before Shuffle ['☁⛈❄']
After Shuffle ['☁⛈❄']`

Actually the same, do you have any idea about the mistake ?

Comment: Ah, I now notice something I didn't before. I will update my answer.